# My Third Party SSL Won't work on Main Domain GoDaddy

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, program-entry-point

So basically my old domain was benscottp.com for my main domain on Godaddy. I changed it last week to Atmosquare.co.nz. I have put a third party ssl on one of my websites before but it was a subdomain. I have provided a screenshot in my manage ssl panel and the ssl certificate that is for the new domain (atmosquare) has the details of the old domain in it? How do I change this as I think it's the reason behind the ssl not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX46a.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

SSL isn't working because it's not issued by a root CA trusted by the browser. There may be other problems also, but that's definitely one of them.

You can't change the certificate. You need to create/order a certificate that covers the domain(s) you want to run SSL on.

You can get free, valid certificates for whatever sites you need from https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: I've used these SSL's before for another website though. They're from Namecheap which are trusted.

Comment: It says right in your screen shot that it's self-signed and not trusted..